# Most extreme chemicals

Tags: discussion, big-list

I know we eschew "lists" on main, but this is a popular search topic and many *good* questions and answers address the question, "For characteristic *X* what is the most extreme chemical?"  E.g.,

- [Strongest acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/17124/5354)
- [Strongest organic acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20283/whats-the-strongest-known-organic-acid)
- Most dangerous: [Is there any substance that's a 4-4-4 on the NFPA diamond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4135/is-there-any-substance-thats-a-4-4-4-on-the-nfpa-diamond)
- [Densest gas](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16439/5354)
- [Densest element](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/21662/5354)
- [Highest melting point](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15141/5354)
- [Greatest range between melting and boiling temperature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33553/5354)
- [Strongest reducing agent](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28568/5354)
- [Lowest solubility product constant](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27842/5354)

The only other good list a quick search turned up was [this thread at Sciencemadness](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=18274).

Can we maintain a list of these here as community wiki?  Alternatively, should we create a [most-extreme](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/most-extreme) for these questions?

Comment: Just created this on the main site: 
http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37425/most-extreme-chemicals

Comment: Any synonyms for "extreme" that could be used to garner more traffic to the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I never said I am against lists, I only said, they tend to create a lot of work.

A list of extreme chemicals as a collection type Q&A might be a good way to catalogue them and create a tiny little compendium. You can totally go for it and create it on the main site. When you do, make sure you explain in good detail how this works.

Once you complete the template, i.e. the question and the corresponding answer, flag it, so that it can be turned into community wiki and locked as such.

---

## BIG, BIG, BIG $\color{red}{\Huge\mathbf{NO}}$ on the tag though.

It is a meta-tag without any use. Worse, whenever there comes a more extreme chemical along the way, a lot of questions will have to be moved around, retagged... etc. pp. So: ***NO!*** I will always kill it with prejudice, immediately.

---

I finally also abused MathJax.
<sub>Thank you for reading.</sub>

Comment: I myself prefer the CW/list-answer solution.  However, just to be clear on the tag alternative: The proposal there was to create *one* new tag [tag:most-extreme] for "Questions about chemical(s) that are the most extreme in some regard."

Comment: Just created this as a main-site community-wiki.  Let's see how it goes!

Comment: +1 for MathJax abuse =D

Comment: I'm not the only one the Mathjax monster is after.